# JSF desktop application

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm interested what are the possible options for using JSF web application as desktop application. In my case I have a JSF wb application which I would like to use as desktop application too (if it's possible).

Comment: You could spin up a lightweight container like Jetty and host the app on the client.

Comment: There seem to be some [web app to desktop integration](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/webapps/) going on in ubuntu although I doubt that they will be supporting servlets or the java EE stack

Answer (score 3):

JSF is a web UI framework. Read your question again. If you want to make a desktop app connected to your web one, you could create some web-services + new desktop UI (Swing, SWT, etc.)